# why are tau-jets narrower compared to quark-jets?

Tags: particle-physics

I read in a thesis (no online link provided) that tau-jets result in a narrower cone in comparison with the other quark/gluon originated jets. I don't understand this. Is this true? If so, why?

Comment: The ratio of mass and transverse momentum apart fromthe R parameter and the clustering algorithm of choice will define the shape of the jet.

Answer (score 2):

The tau decay hadronically thorugh neutrino + Wboson (greater Branching ration). And then the W boson decay in one charged hadron (narrow jets).

In QCD things are a little different, gluons/quarks for example doesn't have neutrino on his decays and then multiplicity on final state is larger, more hadrons produced (wider jets).

And gluons can produce more jets than light quark jets (higher multiplicity), gluons jets are wider than quarks jets.

Comment: Do you know if all jets need a hadron to be defined? Are there non-hadronic jets (in particle physics)?